# How to update edited table so that columns align

Tags: table

I am using table.el in Emacs 24.x on win7. I have created a table and updated the cell contents but cannot get the table to reformat to match the new contents. As far as I have read, EMACS should automatically reformat but it does not seem to. I have tried unrecognizing then re-recognizing the table to update how it is displayed but it remains the untidy mess that I edited. In Org-mode tables, TAB reformats the table after changes but I cannot find out how to do this with the Tables feature. Can someone educate me on how to properly reformat a table after editing its contents?

Comment: Does it ever recognize the table format? I mean have you started fresh with table-insert in a blank document and entered text and yet the reformat does not happen? I ask this because recognize, unrecognize, and release create an unstable formatted table for automatic reformat to work. You have to manually get the table right before auto reformat picks up again.